# why c++fit in mingw bin's dir can't return expected result?

Tags: mingw, c++filt

why c++fit in mingw bin's dir can't return right result?

```
C:\MinGW\bin>c++filt _Z5funcAv
_Z5funcAv
```

but in CentOS system, the c++filt can return right result.

```
#c++filt _Z5funcAv
funcA()
```

how to understand it?

Comment: I have the same problem with no solution :(

Comment: @Buttink， it seems nobody can help us.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across your question, because I had a similar problem with [MinGW32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).

What did work for me was using the `-n` *"Do not ignore a leading underscore"* option, so I suspect a difference in the default option's settings:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>c++filt -n _Z5funcAv
funcA()

C:\MinGW\bin>c++filt _Z5funcAv
_Z5funcAv

C:\MinGW\bin>c++filt __Z5funcAv
funcA()

C:\MinGW\bin>c++filt --version
GNU c++filt (GNU Binutils) 2.25.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```