# Demangling with c++filt on windows - gnu-v3

Tags: c++, demangler

I am trying to properly demangle some symbols taken from a DWARF output.

On Linux, when i do `c++filt --format gnu-v3`.  I can convert `_ZZNV9SomeClass5afuncEiE1x` to `SomeClass::afunc(int) volatile::x`

On Windows, I have installed Mingw32 which includes c++filt.  The same command line yield the input, which means it hasn't been able to demangle.

What could cause this?
I assumed that specifying the format (gnu-v3) would be enough to make it work cross platform.

Comment: what happens without the ` --format gnu-v3` option in Windows? Just found this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225521/why-cfit-in-mingw-bins-dir-cant-return-expected-result. The option `-n` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Same result without format specifier.  But you were right, the `-n` option fixed it. Thank you